# Query Performance in Access 2007 - drawing on a SQL Server Express backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I've been banging my head on this issue for a little while now, and decided I should ask for help.  I have a table which holds temperature/humidity chart recorder data (currently over 775,000 records) from which I am trying to run a statistical query against it.  The problem is that this often will take up to two minutes, and sometimes will not come back at all - causing me to force close the program (Control-Alt-Delete).  At first, I didn't have as much of a problem - it was only after I hit the magical 500k records mark that I started getting serious slowdowns, getting progressively worse as more data was compiled and imported into the table.

Here is the query (pass-through):

```
SELECT dbo.tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned, Min(dbo.tblRecorderLogs.datDateRecorded) AS FirstRecorderDate, Max(dbo.tblRecorderLogs.datDateRecorded) AS LastRecordedDate,
Round(Avg(dbo.tblRecorderLogs.intTempCelsius),2) AS AverageTempC,
Round(Avg(dbo.tblRecorderLogs.intRHRecorded),2) AS AverageRH,
Count(dbo.tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned) AS Records
FROM dbo.tblRecorderLogs
GROUP BY dbo.tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned
ORDER BY dbo.tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned;
```

Here is the table structure in which the chart data is stored:

```
idRecorderDataID     Number     Primary Key
datDateEntered       Date/Time  (indexed, duplicates OK)
datTimeEntered       Date/Time
intTempCelcius       Number
intDewPointCelcius   Number
intWetBulbCelcius    Number
intMixingGPP         Number
intRHRecorded        Number
strAssetRecorder     Text       (indexed, duplicates OK)
strAreaAssigned      Text       (indexed, duplicates OK)
```

I am trying to write a program which will allow people to pull data from this table based on Area Assigned, as well as start and end dates.  With the dataset size I currently have, this kind of report is simply too much for it to handle (it seems) and the machine doesn't ever return an answer.  I've had to extend the ODBC timeout to almost 180 seconds in any queries dealing with this table, simply because of the size.  I could use some serious help, if people have some.  Thank you in advance!

-- Edited 08/13/2012 @ 1050 hours --

I have not been able to test the query on the SQL Server due to the fact that the IT department has taken control of the machine in question, and has someone logged into it full-time using the remote management console.  I have tried an interim step to lessen the impact of the performance issue, but I am still looking for a permanent solution to this issue.

Interim step:

I created a local table mirroring the structure of the dbo.tblRecorderLogs SQL Server table, to which I do a INSERT INTO using the former SELECT statement as it's subquery.  Then any subsequent statistical analysis is drawn from this 'temporary' local table.  After the process is complete, the local table is truncated.

-- Edited 08/13/2012 @ 1217 hours --

Ran the shown query on the SQL Server Management Console, took 1 minute 38 seconds to complete according to the query timer provided by the console.

-- Edit 08/15/2012 @ 1531 hours --

Tried to run query as VBA DoCmd.RunSQL statement to populate a temporary table using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO tblTempRecorderDataStatsByArea ( strAreaAssigned, datFirstRecord, 
datLastRecord, intAveTempC, intAveRH, intRecordCount )
SELECT dbo_tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned, Min(dbo_tblRecorderLogs.datDateRecorded) 
AS MinOfdatDateRecorded, Max(dbo_tblRecorderLogs.datDateRecorded) AS MaxOfdatDateRecorded, 
Round(Avg(dbo_tblRecorderLogs.intTempCelsius),2) AS AveTempC, 
Round(Avg(dbo_tblRecorderLogs.intRHRecorded),2) AS AveRHRecorded, 
Count(dbo_tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned) AS CountOfstrAreaAssigned FROM 
dbo_tblRecorderLogs GROUP BY dbo_tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned ORDER BY 
dbo_tblRecorderLogs.strAreaAssigned
```

The problem arises when the code is executed, the query takes so long - it encounters Timeout before it finishes.  Still hoping for a 'magic bullet' to fix this...

-- Edited 08/20/2012 @ 1241 hours --

The only 'quasi' solution I've found is running the failed query repeatedly (sort of priming the pump, as it were) so that when the query is called again by my program - it has a relative chance of actually completing before the ODBC SQL Server driver times out.  Basically, a filthy filthy hack - but I don't have a better one to combat this issue.

1. I've tried creating a view, which works on the server side - but doesn't speed things up.
2. The proper fields being aggregated are indexed properly, so I can't make any changes there.
3. I am only pulling information from the database that is immediately useful to user - no 'SELECT * madness' going on here.

I think I am, officially, out of things to try - aside from throwing raw computing horsepower at the problem, which isn't a solution right now as the item isn't live, and I have no budget to procure better hardware.  I will post this as an 'answer' and leave it up until Sept 3rd - where if I do not have better answers, I will accept my own answer and accept defeat.

Comment: Are you saying that the query is fine run in SQL Server? (btw, you can use task manager to close.)

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, hopefully the IT guy will have logged off the remote connection by then.

Comment: Due to how the SQL migration tool migrated the table - all Number fields except the primary key are Double numeric field size set with 2 decimal places.  They are not required or indexed.

Comment: How typical, DBA's tying developers hands. My guess is that you are using an OLE/ODBC driver that does not translate MS-Access special functions into their equivalent T-SQL functions. This causes Access to drag all rows across the connection so the query can be evaluated locally. I think this problem will go away when you create an equivalent t-sql view or proc.

Answer (score 0):

When I've had to run min/max functions on several fields from the same table I've often found it quicker to do each column separately as a subquery in the from line of the main/outer query.

So your query would be like this:

```
SELECT rLogs1.strAreaAssigned, rLogs1.FirstRecorderDate, rLogs2.LastRecorderDate, rLog3.AverageTempC, rLogs4.AverageRH, rLogs5.Records
FROM (((
    (SELECT strAreaAssigned, min(datDateRecorded) as FirstRecorderDate FROM dbo.tblRecorderLogs GROUP BY strAreaAssigned) rLogs1
    inner join
    (SELECT strAreaAssigned, Max(datDateRecorded) as LastRecordedDate, FROM dbo.tblRecorderLogs GROUP BY strAreaAssigned) rLogs2
    on rLogs1.strAreaAssigned = rLogs2.strAreaAssigned)
    inner join
    (SELECT strAreaAssigned, Round(Avg(intTempCelsius),2) AS AverageTempC, FROM dbo.tblRecorderLogs GROUP BY strAreaAssigned) rLogs3
    on rLogs1.strAreaAssigned = rLogs3.strAreaAssigned)
    inner join
    (SELECT strAreaAssigned, Round(Avg(intRHRecorded),2) AS AverageRH, FROM dbo.tblRecorderLogs GROUP BY strAreaAssigned) rLogs4
    on rLogs1.strAreaAssigned = rLogs4.strAreaAssigned)
    inner join
    (SELECT strAreaAssigned, Count(strAreaAssigned) AS Records, FROM dbo.tblRecorderLogs GROUP BY strAreaAssigned) rLogs5
    on rLogs1.strAreaAssigned = rLogs5.strAreaAssigned
ORDER BY rLogs1.strAreaAssigned;
```

If you take your query and the one above, copy them into the same query window in SQL Server and run the estimated execution plan you should be able to compare them and see which one works better.

Comment: Its been a while since I've messed with this problem - simply chalking it up to lousy hardware.  I'll try this and see what kind of performance I get out of it.